# Custom Field picklist values in Visual Flows

Tags: apex, community, flow, visual-flows

In my flow, i need to display the picklist values of a custom field in opportunity. How can i achieve this, without necessarily creating them in the flow again. Is there a way to do it?

Actually i have many fields like this to be displayed in the flow. Any pointers would help me from recreating all the fields in the flow.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the plug-in found [here](https://github.com/rajasGit/FlowPicklistSync). There is an idea [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hqtrAAA) that is under point threshold but the PM that created the plug-in commented that it is an enhancement they are working on. The only other way I've heard of people doing is dynamically creating the picklist values based on the options that have been chosen, but that only works if you have records with those values, or placeholder records.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do this apart from building them up manually in the flow designer. One thing I have done is create a custom object to hold all the master values for a number of picklist which I then use in my flow with a type filter to query the values I want for my pick list - make sense?